# Min and max of exponentialy distributed random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If $X$ and $Y$ are i.i.d. exponential as $f_X(x)=\lambda e^{-\lambda x}$ and $f_Y(y)=\lambda e^{-\lambda y}$, and $Z=\min(X,Y)$, then we may say that probability of event $Z=X$ or $Z=Y$ is $\frac 1 2$. This may be valid for any kind of distribution.

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent but not identical exponential as $f_X(x)=\lambda_x e^{-\lambda_x x}$ and $f_Y(y)=\lambda_y e^{-\lambda_y y}$, and $Z=\min(X,Y)$, then how I can find the probability of event $Z=X$ or $Z=Y$ ?.

Most importantly, I need how to find this probability when $X$ and $Y$ have any kind of continuous distributions which are independent.

Comment: Do you mean the probability of $X$ occuring before $Y$ and vice-versa?

Comment: @JeanMarie Both this events are absolutely correct and do not have zero probabilities. $\{\min(X,Y)=X\}=\{X\leq Y\}$.

Comment: @NCh You are right. I misread the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I "think" I understand you are asking, and the probability that $X$ occurs before $Y$ is

$$P(X < Y)=\frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y}$$

and the probability that $Y$ occurs before $X$ is

$$P(Y < X)=\frac{\lambda_y}{\lambda_x+\lambda_y}$$

For the exponential distribution, you can compute this probability like this:

$$ \mathbb{Pr}(X\ will\ finish\ before\ Y) = \int_0^{\infty}\lambda_x e^{-\lambda_x t}e^{-\lambda_y t} dt = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-(\lambda_x + \lambda_y)t} dt = \frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}$$

And, in general

$$\mathbb{Pr}(X\ will\ finish\ before\ Y) = \int_0^{\infty}b_x(t)R_y(t) dt,$$

where $b_x(t)$ is the density of $X$ and $R_y(t)$ is the reliability function of $Y$ -- i.e., $R_y(t)$ = 1 - $F_y(t)$.

Comment: Can you please give me some steps how you derive it? Because I will not always deal with exponential. better to know some general way if you can provide.

Comment: For the exponential distribution: $\mathbb{Pr}(X\ will\ finish\ before\ Y) = \int_0^{\infty}\lambda_x e^{-\lambda_x t}e^{-\lambda_y t} dt = \int_0^{\infty}e^{-(\lambda_x + \lambda_y)t} dt = \frac{\lambda_x}{\lambda_x + \lambda_y}$

Comment: I like your general expression, thanks @PIE